# reported vertical / horizontal camera angle of view is not consistent with supported picture sizes. Which gets clipped or filled on display?

Tags: android-camera

The reported vertical / horizontal camera angle of view is not consistent with supported picture sizes. Presumably this discrepancy is resolved by filling / clipping before an image is returned in the `onPicture()` callback.  How is it resolved?  I would like to correctly measure angles by processing the picture.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the angles of view are consistent with some of the supported picture sizes.  In the 
case of an Samsung Captivate, the angles are reported as 51.2 x 39.4.   Taking the ratio of the tangents of these angles divided by 2, you get 1.338.  This agrees closely enough with the 640x480, 1600x1200, 2048x1536, and 2560x1920 aspect ratios: 1.333...
Additionally, the angles do not change either when you change the picture size, or the zoom, so they are describing the hardware, specifically a relationship between lens and sensor.

So my question only applies to the other picture sizes, having an aspect ratio of 1.66....

Comment: I have discovered that certain tablets (e.g. Samsung SM-T210 - Galaxy Tab 3) have equal horizontal and vertical angles of view (implying aspect ratio = 1), while NONE of the camera1.parameters supported picture sizes have an aspect ratio of 1 (closest being 1.33).  What's going on?  Are pixel pitches different in the x and y directions?  Is come kind of cropping always applied?